# Notify when dialog box appears

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I need to disable a button from a third-party winforms application.
I got the buttons handle using Windows API and WinSpy++, and i have no problem disabling it.

That button is in a DialogBox control. My application is also a winforms app.

How can i be notified when the dialog box appear, so i can disable that button?
Is there an event that can fire when it appears or any workaround?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Doubt there's an event.  Set a timer, loop over open windows every tick, find your window and react.  Best I can think of.  The "too broad" close votes are because that is way too much to explain in this format.  Research [p/invoke of FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html).

Comment: I did consider looping and i got the end result, but i was wondering if there is another way to do it. Anyway, thanks for your thoughts.